# How does the CMTime created when use CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp in iOS? Is it related to systemUptime?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

When I use CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp to get the video frame's presentation timestamp:

```
CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
NSLog(@"pts: %+.3f", CMTimeGetSeconds(pts));
```

the timestamp printed is not based from 0, but almost equal to `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]`. Does this means that the timestamp is generated from systemUptime by lower implementation in iOS? Or if not, where does the timestamp come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes from [`mach_absolute_time()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html) on iOS.

However you can make the timestamps zero based by subtracting the first `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(firstBuffer)` from all the buffers.

Comment: thank you, but I also want to use CMAccelerometerData timestamp to know when the data was sampled, which also use a CMTime.

Comment: Is it possible they're using the same timebase? Hmm apparently not. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42116314/22147
TBH this sounds like something ARKit must have already overcome. Anything useful there?